# difference between runonuithread() and post() while setting adapter in response method

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, okhttp, android-runonuithread

both section of code run fine but which way is better or more suited?
both are written inside the response function(which comes with CallBack interface),and this was basically done to load rest API into my recycler view

```
public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
    final String string=response.body().string();
    ArrayList<User> arrayList = null;
    try{
        arrayList=parseJson(string);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final UserAdapter userAdapter=new UserAdapter(MainActivity.this,arrayList);

  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
        }
    });// FIRST WAY



  recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
        }
    });// SECOND WAY
```

}

obviously one way has commented when other way was used

Comment: see https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java and find `runOnUiThread()` method implementation

Comment: you should check Android sources to see the difference.

Comment: Okay so basically runonUIthread() runs a specified action on the background thread,incase the current thread is a UI thread then the action is excecuted immediately but if  current thread is not a UI thread then the action is posted to the event queue of UI thread . While,the post() method returns boolean value i.e if the runnable was successfully placed in the message queue (true is returned) but the boolean method does not guarantee if the runnable object was 'excecuted' successfully by your looper.So,I think its better to use runonUIthread than post method.Anything you would like to add on?

Comment: so you dont know where to find `View#post` method implementation?

Comment: what exactly do you mean?

Comment: see how `View#post()` method is implemented